# How to retrieve the count and range in the same gremlin query

Tags: titan, gremlin

`g.V().hasLabel('Person').count()` gives me number of person vertices present in my database, and `g.V().hasLabel('Person').range(10,15)` gives me a range of person vertices.

But is there a way to combine these two into a single Gremlin query?

This is just a simplified version of my query, but my actual query is quiet complex and repeating those number of traversals just to find the count, seem ineffective!

Answer (score 2):

I just realized, I could use groovy with gremlin to achieve what I want. Not sure how elegant this is!

`def lst = g.V().hasLabel('Person').toList(); def result = ["count":0, "data":[] ]; result.count=lst.size();result.data=lst[2..3];result`

This is working great even in my complex case.

Comment: You should prefer using Gremlin steps, ie. `count()` and `range()` steps, so the query optimizer can kick in.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, can you please help me with an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend to do a full `count()` in every query. Rather count the total number once and cache it in your application.

That said, here's how you could do it anyway:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Person').aggregate('x').cap('x').
  project('page3', 'total').by(range(local, 10, 15)).by(count(local))
```

**UPDATE:**

In older versions you can try this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Person').aggregate('x').cap('x').as('page3', 'total').
  select('page3', 'total').by(range(local, 10, 15)).by(count(local))
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel for the answer, but when I tried this, I get: `No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.project() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [page3, total]
Possible solutions: reset(), collect(), toSet(), inspect(), sort(), inject(groovy.lang.Closure)
Display stack trace? [yN]`

Comment: I am using titan11 branch with Tinkerpop 3.1.1-incubating

Comment: I am not planning to cache the count in the application, because the data is transactional and the count becomes stale as soon as I serve it in the first response! Hence I would have to do a full count every time. Moreover, this is a sample query and the actual number of vertices / edges I would traverse in full counts would be less because of filters applied.

Comment: Thank you for the update Daniel, but when I tried the as(..).select(..), I get following error `Server could not serialize the result requested. Server error - Error during serialization: Class is not registered: java.util.LinkedList
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(java.util.LinkedList.class);. Note that the class must be serializable by the client and server for proper operation.` What I couldn't understand is the range step when normally used yields results, but in this case is giving LinkedList!

Comment: Well that's looks like an issue in Titan then. `LinkedList` should really be serializable by default. See if you can register a custom serializer (it's documented in the Titan docs how that works).

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I'll try that!